# Compare a sorted and an unsorted file

Tags: linux, file-comparison

I have two files that I want to compare. A sorted and an unsorted one.

ex fileA (sorted)

```
 ABA 
 FRE 
 DIR
```

ex fileB (unsorted)

```
 AJGHEKSLANVJJFABAKEIFJA 
 OPTOEKSMKVMGKVABAALKKSK
```

is there a way to find which words from fileA exist in fileB?

Comment: Are the `#` signs part of the file?

Comment: @EricRenouf no I am sorry. I corrected it

Comment: There are many variations of this question...it's almost boring how many they are... a quick search through my posts [returns this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284679) though I'm sure you'll find plenty more if you take the time to search

Comment: The example fileA is not sorted, at least not lexicographically. The example unsorted fileB is. Is this an error in the examples?

Comment: no I just thought sorted means that every line has only one word. In addition, in the file I have fileA is sorted alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

There may be tools to do it faster, but you could consume the first file in a loop and check like

```
while read -r pat; do
    if grep -q "$pat" fileB; then
        printf '%s has a match' "$pat"
    fi
done < fileA
```

Comment: does this code contains any mistakes?

Comment: @AngelosSouleles I guess that's a hard question to answer for sure, but for me with the sample files you gave it finds `ABA` and not either of the other 2.  It will, as written, treat your words in `fileA` as patterns, not fixed strings.  add `-F` to the `grep` command to fix that if you want.  The `printf` also doesn't include a newline, so that could be a mistake as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
grep -f fileB fileA
```

All the lines from fileA that are there in fileB would be displayed on the console.

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is going for.  For example, `ABA` appears in the middle of the second line, so is a word from fileA that's in fileB, but your search wouldn't report it

Comment: Perhaps yeah, but the question "is there a way to find which words from fileA exist in fileB?" made me think the way I answered the question.

Comment: I would like the ABA on the second line to be reported by the search, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @EricRenouf Apart from the misunderstanting, the `-x` and `-w` options could tackle this problem.

Comment: @Fiximan Since the pattern can appear anywhere in a line, I don't think that `-x` or `-w` will help with this particular problem.  don_cristi's answer that he linked to above has a good potential solution: `grep -oFf fileA fileB | sort -u`

Comment: @Fiximan non of the solutions worked. I tested them with files I knew they have some of the fileA words but I didnt get any result

Comment: @AngelosSouleles @EricRenouf Not what I meant. I was talking about searching for e.g. "A" and matching only lines like "this A that", "A that" and "this A" (`-w` option, note the spaces) or lines that are "A" (and this only, `-x` option), respectively, WITHOUT matching lines like "thisAthat". But it looks like I misunderstood the requirements, when the questioner was referring to "words" that needed matching.